# Delete Elements from an Array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an Array that looks like below

```
[
[0] "The Jungle Book",
[1] {
             "error" => "NO accessor for text",
        "methodName" => "text",
    "receiverString" => "android.widget.LinearLayout{438ce3c8 V.E..... ........ 0,65-148,111 #7f0902b0 app:id/movieScoreRtLayout}",
     "receiverClass" => "android.widget.LinearLayout"
},
[2] "Bruce Reitherman, Phil Harris",
[3] "PG, 1 hr. 18 min.",
[4] {
             "error" => "NO accessor for text",
        "methodName" => "text",
    "receiverString" => "com.flixster.android.view.UnclickableRelativeLayout{42ef9d18 V.E..... ........ 0,1-1080,275}",
     "receiverClass" => "com.flixster.android.view.UnclickableRelativeLayout"
},
[5] {
             "error" => "NO accessor for text",
        "methodName" => "text",
    "receiverString" => "android.widget.ListView{43bd1548 VFED.VC. .F...... 0,0-1080,1542 #7f0901a7 app:id/lvi_listview}",
     "receiverClass" => "android.widget.ListView"
},
[6] {
             "error" => "NO accessor for text",
        "methodName" => "text",
    "receiverString" => "android.widget.FrameLayout{42eeff30 V.E..... ........ 0,0-1080,1701 #1020002 android:id/content}",
     "receiverClass" => "android.widget.FrameLayout"
},
[7] {
             "error" => "NO accessor for text",
        "methodName" => "text",
    "receiverString" => "android.widget.FrameLayout{42e57e98 V.E..... ........ 0,0-1080,1701 #1020011 android:id/tabcontent}",
     "receiverClass" => "android.widget.FrameLayout"
}
```

]

I want to be able to get the resultant array that contains the following:

```
["The Jungle Book" , "Bruce Reitherman, Phil Harris" , "PG, 1 hr. 18 min." ]
```

Comment: Please consider pasting data fragments in plain p or pp format.  The augmented format we see here isn't executable without being edited.

Answer (score 3):

This is a correct example to use [`Enumerable#grep`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep) :

> Returns an array of every element in *enum* for which `Pattern === element`. If the optional block is supplied, each matching element is passed to it, and the block’s result is stored in the output *array*.

```
a = [
  "The Jungle Book",
  { "error" => "NO accessor for text", },
  "Bruce Reitherman, Phil Harris",
  "PG, 1 hr. 18 min.",
  { "error" => "NO accessor for text", },
  { "error" => "NO accessor for text", },
  { "error" => "NO accessor for text", },
  { "error" => "NO accessor for text", }
]

a.grep(String)
# => ["The Jungle Book", "Bruce Reitherman, Phil Harris", "PG, 1 hr. 18 min."]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`Array#delete_if`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_if), you can remove non-string elements:

```
a = [
  "The Jungle Book",
  { "error" => "NO accessor for text", },
  "Bruce Reitherman, Phil Harris",
  "PG, 1 hr. 18 min.",
  { "error" => "NO accessor for text", },
  { "error" => "NO accessor for text", },
  { "error" => "NO accessor for text", },
  { "error" => "NO accessor for text", }
]
a.delete_if { |x| ! x.is_a? String } # OR a.delete_if { |x| x.is_a? Hash }
a
# => ["The Jungle Book", "Bruce Reitherman, Phil Harris", "PG, 1 hr. 18 min."]
```

Or as Arupt Rakshit commented, you can use [`Array#select!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-select-21) or [`Array#keep_if`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-keep_if):

```
a.select! { |x| x.is_a? String }

a.keep_if { |x| x.is_a? String }
```

Comment: @ArupRakshit, In the title, `delete` is explicitly mentioned. I assumed that the OP want to delete element in place. BTW, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: updated the answer to include an alternative solution that use `Array#select!`, `Array#keep_if`.

Comment: You can also do - `a.select!(&String.method(:===))`... more shorter version... :-)